# Copy files path from a specific directory onwards - Bash

Tags: linux, bash, directory, copy, filesystems

How can I copy files (including their folder hierarchy), from a specific directory onwards using Bash?

For example, let's say I have the following files:

- /first/second/third/1.txt
- /first/third/2.txt
- /first/second/3.txt

I'd like to copy the files (1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt) path **after** the /first/ directory, meaining the result should be:

- /second/third/1.txt
- /third/2.txt
- /second/3.txt

Using the following command but unfortunately it includes the entire path including the 'first' directory, so it requires some adjustments:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec cp --parent {} destination_folder/
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: cd into `/first/`, and run this command:
`find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec cp --parent -t destination_folder/ {} +`

Comment: @oguzismail That's the problem, I can't cd because it's part of a larger script. I need to be able to manipulate the "find" relative path output :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not possible to do `cd first` before `find`, try to do it in `-exec`:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec bash -c 'cd first; echo cp --parent "${1#./*/}" ../destination_folder/' _ {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can execute the `find`, you should also be able to do the `cd`.
Perhaps what you need is a subshell, so that the `cd` does not persist beyond the `find`?

```
: commands before, in $someDir
( cd /first/ && # in subshell, only local env logs new dir 
  find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec cp --parent -t $destination_folder/ {} + 
) # subshell ends, parent never changed logged dir
: commands after - still in $someDir
```